# Is there any tool for generating decision table from cause effect graph?

Tags: test-design, tools, test-techniques, test-tools

I learned about cause effect graphing and it looks like a valuable test case generating method.
The issue is that it's hard to generate the decision table from the graph by hand.
So I was wondering if there is a tool that automates this step?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendation does not attract answers, instead showcase what you tried and then ask for help.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable question, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BenderRBT](http://www.benderrbt.com/bendersoftware.htm#rbt) test case design tool has cause-effect graphing test case design component. [Manual](http://www.benderrbt.com/BenderRBT-Cause-Effect%20Graphing%20User%20Guide.pdf) is available here.